# Can Eight Retrograde (seen from Earth) planets occur?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, positional-astronomy, ecliptic

First of all, for the purposes of this question Pluto is a planet. So the eight planets being considered are Mercury, Venus, Mars, Jupter, Saturn, Uranus, Neptune and Pluto.

My question is: can all eight of these planets *go retrograde<sup>†</sup>* at the same time? I know that seven can do so on rare instances; there were 12 days of that in the 20th century all in the 1940's and the 1980's. But to show how rare that is there was a block of 400 years in the middle ages with no days of seven retrogrades. Has eight ever happened? Or is it impossible?

<sup>†</sup>Retrograde motion as seen from Earth, not retrograde orbits around the Sun.

Comment: Since there is no perfect resonance in the planets' orbits, such an event must be possible.

Comment: Is there astronomy simulation software that would show me? The problem child planet is Venus because that always remains prograde when the other seven go retrograde.

Comment: There is a perfect mean-motion resonance between pluto and neptune

Comment: Isn't this basically the same as asking when all planets will be lined up on one side of the Sun?  Inferior planets (Mercury & Venus) need to be near inferior conjunction to be in retrograde, while superior planets (the rest) need to be near opposition.

Comment: Since the periods of all the non-Pluto planets are non-resonant, the probabilities that they're retrograde are effectively independent.  Taking the numbers from the [Wikipedia page on retrograde motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apparent_retrograde_motion), you can find that (for example) Mars is in retrograde 72/780 of the time.  Multiplying all these probabilities together, all eight "real" planets will be in retrograde about 0.0023% of the time.  The chances if you include Pluto are necessarily less than that.

Comment: I am not sure about using probabilities of retrogrades; the main obstacle to 8 retrogrades seems to be having venus and mercury retrograde at the same time. That's why the five inner planets being all retrograde at once is rarer than 7 retrogrades.

Comment: This is interesting and I'm working on a better answer, but if you google "all eight planets retrograde at same time" or similar phrases (no quotes), you'll get a lot of astrology links suggesting up to 7 planets have retrograded at the same time. Regardless of whether you believe in astrology, the calculations they use should be astronomically accurate. A little digging might find an 8 planet retrograde.

Comment: Its a perfect  mean-motion resonance, there is all sorts of complex motions, but on average and in the long term, pluto is locked at 2:3 with Neptune.  It is a fact of no consequience for this question. It is possible for Neptune and pluto to both be at opposion (and hense retrograde) at the same time

Comment: More to come, but https://github.com/barrycarter/bcapps/tree/master/ASTRO/all-retrogrades.txt.bz2 now lists all retrogrades +- 15,000 years from now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**EDIT: I used the DE431 ephemeris to get the results below. However, if you visit HORIZONS (https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons.cgi) and create an ephemeris for Pluto (actually Pluto's barycenter, object 999), the results include this warning:**

> The Horizons output log may report using DE431 as the source of target
>   or center data, but it is nevertheless using DE433 as an override if
>   Pluto is involved. This is to maintain ephemeris consistency for the
>   New Horizons  spacecraft encounter at Pluto.

**Therefore, my calculations may be inaccurate, above and beyond the normal inaccuracy of predicting planetary data in the past and future.**

There are 2 times in the past 15,000 years and 5 times in the next 15,000 years where all 8 planets are in retrograde as observed from Earth.

The table below lists the times when this happens:

- The last column is the ephemeris time, the number of seconds since '2000-JAN-01 12:00:00 UTC', which NASA refers to as "the epoch".
- The first line in each pair shows the start time of when all 8 planets are in retrograde, and the final planet to enter retrograde to make this true.
- The second line in each pair shows the end time when at least one planet is no longer in retrograde, and the planet whose retrograde period has ended.

```
B.C. 12435-AUG-10 07:52 JUPITER STARTS RETROGRADE -455482152466.038696
B.C. 12435-AUG-24 17:12 MERCURY ENDS RETROGRADE -455480909251.797852

B.C.  4139-MAR-23 15:02 MARS STARTS RETROGRADE -193692373029.630005
B.C.  4139-MAR-28 21:57 MERCURY ENDS RETROGRADE -193691916114.978455

A.D.  7662-APR-27 19:33 MARS STARTS RETROGRADE 178685595220.195740
A.D.  7662-MAY-12 05:19 NEPTUNE ENDS RETROGRADE 178686840014.478882

A.D.  8807-JAN-07 02:02 MERCURY STARTS RETROGRADE 214808680981.726929
A.D.  8807-JAN-20 01:05 JUPITER ENDS RETROGRADE 214809800771.851685

A.D. 10575-FEB-14 21:34 VENUS STARTS RETROGRADE 270604748086.593933
A.D. 10575-FEB-24 18:53 NEPTUNE ENDS RETROGRADE 270605602468.037781

A.D. 13679-NOV-06 16:03 VENUS STARTS RETROGRADE 368580427477.379639
A.D. 13679-NOV-19 01:05 MERCURY ENDS RETROGRADE 368581496795.683594

A.D. 16364-MAR-11 19:25 MERCURY STARTS RETROGRADE 453290109945.561157
A.D. 16364-MAR-13 08:53 MARS ENDS RETROGRADE 453290244824.895996
```

Notes and caveats:

- I wrote https://github.com/barrycarter/bcapps/tree/master/ASTRO/bc-retrograde.c to print out retrograde times for all planets.
- The file https://github.com/barrycarter/bcapps/tree/master/ASTRO/all-retrogrades.txt.bz2 shows start and end retrograde times for all 8 planets. NOTE: the lines indicating that planets leave retrograde at "17191-MAR-01 00:00" is incorrect-- that's simply the maximum time for which I could make calculations.
- I wrote https://github.com/barrycarter/bcapps/tree/master/ASTRO/bc-moving-backwards.pl to determine which planets were in retrograde at any given time, and used the results to find the times above where all 8 planets were in retrograde.
- I spot checked my results against https://www.calsky.com/ -- note that I am computing "ecliptic retrograde", when a planet's ecliptic longitude is decreasing, not "equatorial retrograde", when a planet's right ascension is decreasing.
- As always, I invite people to double check my results, and remind everyone not to use my results for anything critical.

Comment: That is awesome! Unless there's anything else left to add I'm going to tick your response. Thank you very much! Just what I was loking for!

Comment: What would be even better would be to match up the calculations to a theoretical reason for eight retrograde planets as I listed them being possible. In any case I think that you [barrycarter] should get some sort of medal and/or points bonus for the answer because that was probably one of the hardest questions ever asked on Stack.

Comment: Verified 7662, 8807, 10575 in Stellarium (VSOP87).

Comment: @barrycarter 4139 BCE (-4138) in Stellarium, Pluto appears prograde in late March, all others retrograde.

Comment: @MikeG I'm too lazy to check myself, but could you try HORIZONS: https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons.cgi#top for Pluto in 4139 BCE? The C library I use comes from NASA and is the same one used to generate HORIZONS (roughly speaking).

Comment: @barrycarter HORIZONS refuses to give an ephemeris for Pluto outside [1900, 2100].

Comment: When I chose Pluto barycenter (9), it says "Available time span for currently selected target body:1549-Dec-21 to 2650-Jan-25 TT", and I managed to generate an ephemeris for 1550-2649. Pluto (999) is available for a shorter period, but this is true of most planets-- generally, it's better to use the system barycenter for longer coverage. Of course, this is bad either way, because it doesn't cover the time frame I used. I used the DE431 ephermeris, so i'm not sure why HORIZONS is balking. It might be that DE436 negates DE431's results?

Comment: OK, edited answer to note DE431 no longer considered accurate for Pluto.

Comment: With DE431 data (2.6 GB download) Stellarium has Pluto retrograde in your 4139 BCE window too.

Comment: I think that is such a complex and data driven question that I will hold off on giving a "best" answer until people have done as much work on it as they want to do.

Comment: The files that @barrycarter/user21 refers to in [their answer](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/32463/7982), especially the large file of all planet retrogrades will still be helpful here. However currently The Github account linked to is no longer available. Does anyone (perhaps @snack_food_termite) happen to have a copy of them?

Comment: I modified the wording to make this more answer-like. I wonder though if you can also ask this as a new question, either here in the main site or in [Astronomy SE meta](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: @getastro Unfortunately, it looks like barrycarter never licensed his github repo. This means that he retains full copyright, and now that he has removed the repository from public access it cannot legally be shared here.

Comment: @uhoh See above.

Comment: @called2voyage thanks, got it!

Comment: @uhoh I did make a meta post about this, because this made me grumble, lol.